# R date-time format in empty data frame

Tags: r, datetime, dataframe, format

I am attempting to set up an empty data frame in R which will be populated by, amongst other things, two date-timestamps in the form of e.g. 21/08/2014 20:51.

This is my code:

```
eventised <- data.frame(student_id=integer(),
                        session_id=integer(), 
                        start_ts=as.POSIXct(format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"), 
                        stop_ts=as.POSIXct(format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M"),                         
                        week=integer(),
                        macro_process=character(),
                        micro_process=character(),
                        stringsAsFactors=FALSE) 

raw_events <- read.csv(file="SRL_Concat_ST1_Test_2.csv", header = TRUE, sep=",") 

last_sess_ID <- 0

for (row in 1:nrow(raw_events)) {
  if(raw_events[row, "SESSION_ID"] != last_sess_ID || row == nrow(raw_events)) {
    print(row)
    if(row !=1) {
      eventised[nrow(eventised)+1,] <- c(r_student_id, r_session_id, r_start_ts, r_stop_ts, r_week, "MAC", "MIC")
#      eventised[nrow(eventised)+1,] <- c(r_student_id, r_session_id, r_week, "MAC", "MIC")
    }

    r_student_id <- raw_events[row, "STUDENT_ID"]
    r_session_id <- raw_events[row, "SESSION_ID"]
    r_start_ts <- raw_events[row, "TIMESTAMP"]
    r_stop_ts <- raw_events[row, "TIMESTAMP"]
    r_week  <- raw_events[row, "WEEK"]
    last_sess_ID <- raw_events[row, "SESSION_ID"]
  } else {
    r_stop_ts <- raw_events[row, "TIMESTAMP"]
  }
```

I get this error:
Error in inherits(x, "POSIXct") : 
  argument "x" is missing, with no default

Then later I attempt to do this:
          eventised[nrow(eventised)+1,] <- c(r_student_id, r_session_id, r_start_ts, r_stop_ts, r_week, "MAC", "MIC")

I get:
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

I am probably doing something stupid but I would really appreciate some help.

Thanks in advance,

F

DATA

STUDENT_ID  SESSION_ID  TIMESTAMP   LACTION_TYPE    WEEK    STUDY_MODE
4   7   11/08/2014 23:08    CONTENT_ACCESS  3   revisiting

Comment: Can you give a sample of your data?

Comment: Can you try with `as.POSIXct(character(), format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")` instead of `as.POSIXct(format = "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")`?

Comment: STUDENT_ID SESSION_ID TIMESTAMP LACTION_TYPE WEEK STUDY_MODE
4 7 11/08/2014 23:08 CONTENT_ACCESS 3 revisiting
4 7 11/08/2014 23:13 CONTENT_ACCESS 3 revisiting
4 7 11/08/2014 23:13 CONTENT_ACCESS 3 revisiting
4 7 11/08/2014 23:13 CONTENT_ACCESS 3 revisiting
4 7 11/08/2014 23:14 CONTENT_ACCESS 3 revisiting

Comment: Aurele, that did get me a bit further. When I go here: eventised[nrow(eventised)+1,] <- c(r_student_id, r_session_id, r_start_ts, r_stop_ts, r_week, "MAC", "MIC"), I get an error around r_start_ts:

Comment: Error in as.POSIXlt.character(x, tz, ...) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Comment: I think you are approaching your problem from the wrong end. You should import the data and then append it via do.call or some other 'rolling' method.

Comment: HI Roman, I'm pretty new to R. Not quite sure what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

This should take care of the datetime format:

```
df <- data.frame(start_ts=as.POSIXct(character()))
```